# How to install lastest version of Node and NPM for Linux Debian?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a Debian Jessie  and latest Node version available with apt is 8.9.0.

What's the easy way to install the latest version aka 11.3.0 ?
(and the latest NPM also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest way to manage `Node.js` versions is to use [n](https://github.com/tj/n)

#### Installation

```sh
$ curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash
```

#### Usage

```sh
$ n 11.3.0 #Install node 11.3.0 version
$ n latest #Install or activate the latest node release
$ n stable #Install or activate the latest stable node release
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way seems to be :

**INSTALLATION**

1. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ and copy url of your architecture Linux binaries (here Linux Binaries x64)
2. Install `xz-utils` if needed : `sudo apt-get install xz-utils`
3. write these commands

commands :

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.3.0/node-v11.3.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
unxz node-v11.3.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
sudo tar --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xf node-v11.3.0-linux-x64.tar
rm node-v11.3.0-linux-x64.tar
```

It should untar the archive in `/usr/local` which is already in the `PATH` and `secure_path`.

---

**TEST**

`node -v` return `v11.3.0`

`npm -v` return `6.4.1`

---

**UPDATE**

To update, just make the same with new version and update NPM packages with `npm update` (not tested yet).